# Parent <div> class applying options too far down the chain ( nav > ui > li affects nav > ui > li > ui > li )

Tags: html, css

I'll apologize ahead of time as my experience with HTML and CSS, is very limited.

I have a navigation class that appears to pass options too far down the chain. I don't really understand why this is happening, and I haven't had much luck in locating a reason. I was wondering if someone could explain WHY this is happening, and possibly offer a solution to prevent it from happening.

I have posted a JSFiddle and an example of what I'm talking about below.

```
nav > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:32px; <-- THIS LINE..
    }

nav > ul > li > ul > li { <-- IS SOME HOW AFFECTING THIS CHILD CLASS
    display:block;
    }
```

When this happens it applies a line-height of 32px to both the first and second level of the navigation menu, but I can't figure out why. I have considered zeroing out the line-height in my reset.css, but I'm not sure if that is the right answer.

https://jsfiddle.net/tua083fr/2/

Thanks, and sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Most CSS properties are inherited by child elements.

Comment: Funny thing: `nav>ul>li {color:red}` also affects the `nav>ul>li>ul>li`!!

Comment: You're experiencing CSS inheritance.  Many properties of parent elements are inherited by child elements.  Look up info on an individual CSS property to find out if it is an inherited property.  Read more about inheritance here:  http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you can't define or re-define the desired line-height further down the cascade?

```
    nav > ul > li > ul > li {
        display:block;
        line-height: 10px; /* HERE ! */
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tua083fr/3/

Or, alternatively, apply your `line-height` to the `<a>` child instead of the `<li>` (since `<li>` styling is applied to all its children, including dropdown `<ul>` and its own `<li>` children) ?

```
nav > ul > li > a {
    line-height:32px; /* Remove this from nav > ul > li declaration */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tua083fr/5/

Comment: In my production version, I have it defined as such. I'm just trying to remove a level of unpredictability for someone like me. Would setting the line-height to 0 in my reset.css change this behavior at all? I was also wondering if this only affects <li> elements under <nav>, or if this behavior is set for the remainder of the document. Thanks.

Comment: Seems I have answered my own question about the above. If I set line-height:0 under my reset.css then the child classes do not inherit the property. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

li's are naturally block level elements, so no need for display: block. Inheritance of the line-height has to do with traversing the dom and the execution order.

Comment: the execution is bottom up (from innermost to topmost element, similar to event bubbling) so your second css entry satisfies the 1st; in that, apply line-height: 32px; to all li's that are children of ul that are children of the nav

Comment: I have set display to none in my reset.css which is why I have it defined as block.